# Why is the derivative of a $m$-linear map the sum of $(m−1)$-linear functions

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, proof-explanation, multilinear-algebra

I'm reading about the derivative of multilinear maps

> [image]

The author said that the derivative of a $m$-linear map is the sum of $(m−1)$-linear functions. But it seems to me that the each summand in the formula 
 below is also a $m$-linear map $$\partial \varphi\left(x_{1}, \ldots, x_{m}\right)\left(h_{1}, \ldots, h_{m}\right)=\sum_{j=1}^{m} \varphi\left(x_{1}, \ldots, x_{j-1}, h_{j}, x_{j+1}, \ldots, x_{m}\right)$$

Because $\varphi\left(x_{1}, \ldots, x_{m}\right)$ is a $m$-linear map, so is $\varphi\left(x_{1}, \ldots, x_{j-1}, h_{j}, x_{j+1}, \ldots, x_{m}\right)$.

Could you please explain what I'm missing? Thank you so much!

Comment: $(h_1,...,h_m)$ is a point where derivative is taken, so you can think of it as fixed but arbitrary.

Comment: So $\varphi\left(x_{1}, \ldots, x_{j-1}, h_{j}, x_{j+1}, \ldots, x_{m}\right)$ is a function of $(m-1)$ variables for every fixed $(h_1,...,h_m)$